# Do multiple signals in C result in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, signals

When running my code, it crashes and says "Segmentation fault".

However, when I run through it in gdb, it crashes due to a SIGABRT error not a SIGSEGV.

Are there other signals that also "map" to a general Segmentation fault error on the terminal?

Comment: The debugging environment may be slightly different from the non-debugging environment, so the bug (possibly an uninitialized pointer) is manifesting itself in different ways, leading to different crashes.  But the direct answer to your question is "only SIGSEGV leads to a segmentation fault".

Answer (score 0):

abort() sends the calling process the SIGABRT signal, this is how SIGABRT or Signal 6 is generated. Also, most "assert" implementations make use of SIGABRT in case of a failed assert.

abort() is usually called by library functions which detect an internal error or some seriously broken constraint. For example malloc() will call abort() if its internal structures are damaged by a heap overflow.

SIGSEGV or Signal 11, officially know as "segmentation fault", means that the program accessed a memory location that was not assigned. That's usually a bug in the program. So if you're writing your own program, that's the most likely cause. otherwise I do not see any other signal will create segmentation fault in a program.